# Peak finding from a distribution in Julia

Tags: statistics, julia, data-science, distribution

I have a distribution as a vector in Julia. I can plot a histogram and/or a kde of for this data, but I want to find the peak values. The naive way in which I am doing it is to plot the histogram and then just retrieve the mode of the data in the vector used to plot the histogram. However, this output is sometimes not close to the peak I can see from the histogram. What do I do?

Comment: Well, if I had to do it, I think I would approximate the data with a Gaussian mixture density (similar to a kernel density, but with many fewer bumps than data), and then use a numerical method to find the maximum of the Gaussian mixture density.

Comment: @RobertDodier Could you point me to some resource on how to do that? I am new to both Julia and this kind of statistical analysis.

Comment: Well, to read up about Gaussian mixtures, I think I would look at Wikipedia. I don't know any specific Julia package for it but I imagine there would be one. If a web search for "Julia package Gaussian mixture" doesn't find anything, you could try asking on a Julia-specific forum (which, again, I think a web search will find).

Comment: A Gaussian mixture density is just a weighted sum (specifically a convex sum, i.e. the weights add up to 1) of Gaussian densities, so it's a smooth function. There are numerical methods for maximizing smooth functions of one variable, which I think a web search will find. (Likewise in two or dimensions, there are numerical methods for maximizing, but the methods are different than for one dimension.)

Comment: > Julia-specific forum (which, again, I think a web search will find) ||| The Discourse forum (http://discourse.julialang.org/) is probably the best place to ask. There's also a Zulip "statistics" stream (https://julialang.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/231228-statistics), and likely an equivalent on Slack too.

Comment: Today I came across https://github.com/halleysfifthinc/Peaks.jl which could perhaps be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

If your data are unimodal or otherwise can be fit to a single distribution, you can do this pretty simply with something like LsqFit.jl. For example

```
# First, let's just generate some standard normal data and take
# a histogram of that so we have something to fit
data = randn(10000).+1.23
binedges = -4:0.01:4
using NaNStatistics
y = histcounts(data, binedges)
x = (binedges[1:end-1]+binedges[2:end])/2 # bin centers

# Now, let's fit a distribution to this data
using Distributions, LsqFit
model(x,p) = pdf.(Normal(p[1],abs(p[2])), x).*p[3]
f = curve_fit(model, x, y, [1., 1., 1.])
μ, σ, normconst = f.param
```

I get something along the lines of

```
julia> μ, σ, normconst = f.param
3-element Vector{Float64}:
   1.2323678141604881
   1.0071043070748935
 100.18149764598088
```

so pretty good relative to the input